What is the correct syntax for RainLoop's ldap-contacts-suggestions plugin?
I'm trying to get RainLoop v1.17.0 (running on Ubuntu 22.04) to connect to an MS 2016 AD LDAP server, but each time it fails silently. Do I need to include ldap:// in the hostname? Quotes around the user dn? How to format the access dn? I can run ldapsearch from the CLI without a problem, so I think my RainLoop LDAP config isn't quite right.
Logs don't seem to produce anything helpful, but maybe the plugin isn't configured to generate logs, or I'm looking in the wrong place.
Here's my "ldap-contacts-suggestions" plugin config:
LDAP hostname - ldap://192.168.X.X 
LDAP port - 389
Access dn (login) - "cn=LDAP_USER,ou=SERVICES,dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM"
Access password - XXXXXXXX
Users DN format - "ou=USERS,dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM"
objectClass value - person
Search field - uid
Name field - name
Mail field - mail
Allowed emails - *

I'm expecting some kind of selection menu to appear when I compose a message and begin typing a name or email in the To: field, but nothing happens. Thanks for any help.
Cheers,
CPN9

For anyone out there who's wondering the syntax is as follows for establishing an ldap (not ldaps) connection. No quotes or spaces after the commas in the "Users DN Format" field.
ldap://192.168.X.X
389
DOMAIN\user
ou=USERS,dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM
person
uid
name
mail
*

Cheers,
CPN9
